# Using for loops to enter data into arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop

So I have this C++ program that contains .h file and main.cpp. In .h I have this class:

```
class Plaza
{
public:

    int length;
    double x;
    double y;

    Plaza();
    ~Plaza();

};
```

In main.cpp, I am trying to enter the data using for loop, and I manage to store data for `int i = 0` state, but when `i` is increased, no data that has been entered is being stored into array. For the inside loop, I tried to put `j < n`, `j < n-1` and `j < n+1`, but it's not working. How can I store all the data and print it out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Plaza.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    Plaza *obj1;

    cout << "Enter limit number (N): ";
    cin >> n;

    obj1 = new Plaza[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter length, x and y for " << i + 1 << ". plaza: " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            cin >> obj1[j].length;
            cin >> obj1[j].x >> obj1[j].y;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << obj1[i].x << " " << obj1[i].y << " Length=" << obj1[i].length;
    }

    delete[] obj1;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the print I get:

[image]

Comment: What is the `j` loop for?  Your input loop  should look just like your output loop.

Comment: I think that solves the problem, J loop is not needed, thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: No need to use naked `new` at all here. Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Enter length, x and y for " << i + 1 << ". plaza: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        cin >> obj1[j].length;
        cin >> obj1[j].x >> obj1[j].y;
    }
}
```

Here's your culprit. Get rid of the inner for-loop (not the cin-statements, just the for... line and its closing bracket) and replace `obj[j]` with `obj[i]`. You are currently repeatedly writing to `obj[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for help, I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter length, x and y for " << i + 1 << ". plaza: " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            cin >> obj1[j].length;
            cin >> obj1[j].x >> obj1[j].y;
        }
    }
```

Why there is a need of second for loop., if you check the j value, it is always 0 so only one value is inserted.,

 try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "Enter length, x and y for " << i + 1 << ". plaza: " << endl;

                cin >> obj1[i].length;
                cin >> obj1[i].x >> obj1[i].y;
           }
        }
```